# Leaking objects, and I need to fix it

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

I'm importing some older ObjC code, circa 2006, to the latest Xcode. It was written before the era of ARC, and I don't have a strong handle on the previous system. Looking for some advice on how to diagnose these.

Here's an example, one of hundreds...

```
sym = [ globals addObject:[ [ NCObject alloc ] initWithArray:saved dimension:dimension type:type ] ] ;
```

The error isn't specific, do I need an autorelease around the entire thing, or one immediately after "type ]"?

I seem to recall that the basic rule is that if I see an inti, I need to autorelease it. Are there other cases I need to think about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `alloc...` (any method that starts with `alloc`), `new`, `copy...`, `mutableCopy...` give you retained objects (thanks to @jlehr for extending the original list).
2. Collections retain
   objects that are contained in them (in your case, `globals` retains
   that `NCObject` that you create.
3. You should balance every retain
   **that you write** with a `release` or `autorelease`. If you `release` an object, you can't use it anymore, because if its
   `retainCount` has reached zero, it will be deallocated instantly. An
   autoreleased object will live until the nearest `autoreleasepool`
   drain.

In the example that you wrote, you either have to balance an `alloc`, so you have to either `release` your `NCObject` after you've added it to the array (if you `release` it before that, it will most likely be deallocated), or `autorelease` it whenever you want.

But I would really recommend you to read Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf). It's short. And it describes all the rules that you'll need.

Comment: You mean `alloc`, not `init` in this answer, right?

Comment: @danh, yes, sorry, thank you :) I'll edit it in a moment. It's almost 3 a.m. here :) Time to go to sleep, I guess :)

Comment: Item 1 is incomplete: in addition, `allocWithZone:`, `copy`, `copyWithZone:`, `mutableCopy`, and `mutableCopyWithZone:`, and in general any methods whose names begin with `alloc` or `new` all transfer ownership to the caller.

Comment: @jlehr, thank you, I updated my answer. I forgot about `copy...`/`mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Autorelease is right.  The alloc creates an rc=+1 object.  Adding it to the array makes it +2.  Autorelease will leave it at +1, which is where you want it.  Releasing the `globals` array eventually will bring it back to 0, which is also desired behavior.

For clarity:

```
sym = [[NCObject alloc] initWithArray:saved dimension:dimension type:type];
[globals addObject:sym];
[sym autorelease];
```

Note that `release` is just as good in this case (a little better because it doesn't leave any autorelease pool work for later).  Unless the function returns sym, you can release.

Comment: If you aren't going to inline the allocation and insertion, using release instead of autorelease should work fine. You use autorelease inline because you want to decrement the retainCount after the array has incremented it.

Comment: Ok one related one... in the `-(id)init` method it does a `self = [super init]`, should I autorelease self? That seems odd, but it follows the pattern.

Comment: nope.  in this context, init is just like any other method that is unconcerned with memory management of the object.

Comment: Ok cool. And just as cool, I never tried double-clicking on one of these warnings - WOW, that's super useful!